# Show hide text areas using radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change what text areas are visible depending on what radio button is checked.

I have followed various guides on google and none have worked.

This is what I currently have, using the click function but still nothing.

HTML:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <!-- Header Delimitation input settings -->
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label class="control-label" for="header_delimitation">Header delimitation</label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="radio">
                <label for="header_delimitation-0">
                <input type="radio" name="header_delimitation" id="header_delimitation-0" value="0">
Fixed Column Width</label>
            </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label for="header_delimitation-1">
                        <input type="radio" name="header_delimitation" id="header_delimitation-1" value="1">
                    Character delimiter
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group" id="header_col_form">
                <label class="control-label" for="header_columns_num">Number of Columns</label>
                <div class="">
                    <input id="header_columns_num" name="header_columns_num" type="text" placeholder="number" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group" id="header_delim_form">
                    <label class=" control-label" for="header_delim">Header delimiter</label>
                    <div class="">
                        <input id="header_delim" name="header_delim" type="text" placeholder="delimiter" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#header_col_form').hide('fast');
    $('#header_delim_form').hide('fast');

    $('#header_delimitation-0').click(function () {
        $('#header_col_form').show('fast');
        $('#header_delim_form').hide('fast');
    });

    $('#header_delimitation-1').click(function () {
        $('#header_delim_form').show('fast');
        $('#header_col_form').hide('fast');
    });
});
```

[How it looks like now](https://jsfiddle.net/eganf704/)

So functionality wise, it should when header_delimitation_0 is selected, show header_col_form and hide header_delim_form. I will then add the reverse for when header_delimitation_1 is selected.

There is most likely a far simpler and cleaner way of completing this task, if so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works ... just include jQuery ,-). In the "Javascript" section, click on Javascript (blue link) and include jQuery in the "Frameworks and Extensions" section

Comment: I have the following in my base html file. `script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/omaub7r7/) with the same :

Comment: aha! it works! okay so JavaScript was correct but why are the JS scripts in my base html file not accessible by this html file?? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: How about Include jQuery in this HTML file as well ?

Comment: that's not a problem, I can do that. I was under the impression the reason for having a base html file was so that you only needed to include these links once :)

Comment: What's your "base HTML file"? How is it linked to your actual page? Is it like a Master Page in ASP.NET, or an include in PHP, or something else?